# What happen in episode 13.5?

Tags: angel-beats

After the last episode (ep 13),

> Everyone graduate except Otonashi and all the NPC disappear, but there's episode 13.5 where Otonashi become student council president replacing Kanade place, and all NPC and one regular student (non-NPC) appear again. Did they reset the after life world?

What exactly happen here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The so-called "episode 13.5," titled "Another Epilogue" was released as an extra on the BD/DVD exclusive. Depicted is an short **alternate ending** where Otonashi remains in the school and becomes the new student council president, in order to help other students (like how Tenshi did) to pass on. It's really a "what-if" scenario rather than an actual epilogue.

Comment: so the actual epilogue will be Otonashi graduate with Kanade right after she graduate?

Comment: It is implied that way, yes.

Comment: I was about to accept your answer then I realize something, your answer seems to explain that this is only alternate ending but didn't explain what happen here, or am I missing something? Did they reset the after life world and Otonashi choose to stay or what?

Comment: As I said in my answer, this is an alternate ending where Otonashi remains (instead of passing on) in the school and becomes the new student council president. Nothing reset, no one chose anything... it's merely a what-if. What if Otonashi remained, like the creator of the system Tenshi uses.